# VectorCast test function pointer

Tags: unit-testing

I am having problems testing a scenario in VectorCast. Dont know what it expects ?

here is the thing.

I am testing a function - say FuncA which calls int FuncB ( ENUM, &FuncC )

I want to Stub FuncB and pass Enum and check if FuncC address is passed.

While stubbing, user code for the second parameter I gave was like this

<> = ( FuncC );

I tried putting it in Input and Expected section both

It takes lot of time t execute and then fails with the Harness Error

Can you please give a solution to this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the minimal code you have that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I resolved the problem today morning thanks -  basically it wasnt about the function with function pointer parameter but a problem about Vectorcast testing the RTOS function. I think it is unable to resolve the Kernel function and generates an exception. Since the function which I had mentioned was called immediately after this kernel function, and the code coevrage showed its not called, I thought its a problem with the function pointer problem.   If ( var A ) {  call kernel function; } Call funcC ( func pointer )

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer and then accept it? That will help others in future. Thanks